# Changing a label's text on window

Tags: ollydbg

I'm using OllyDbg v2 for debugging. Target is a simple executable file with few labels. It has been written in C++ builder. Looks like labels are located dynamically, so I can't get its text using OllyDbg, let alone changing the text. What should I do?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the VCL _draws_ a `TLabel` (i.e. it's a pseudo-control element), as opposed to "static controls" which are standard controls known from years ago. So _if_ the forms are contained in the resources you may be able to see/manipulate them there, but it's a different story from other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the executable in resource hacker see if you can see them with that